# How to render div's dynamically in Vue?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to add button on my page. When we click that button, above generates div where we can add photo. When we click twice, we have two divs etc. The problem is that my code is not generating... How I can achieve this?

And another question. How I can add +1 to identifier while adding another div?

```
<div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
    <div class="col-3">
        <photo :upload_url="" :parent="this" identifier="image01" :value="row.photo">
        </photo>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>


addRow: function(){
    this.rows.push({photo: ""});
},
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't need to pass the `parent` as it should be accessible in the child component as `$parent` anyway. What is the v-model for on the `div`? Also, can you show the code for the `photo` component?

Answer (score 0):

To add +1 to div you can have `index` var in v-for:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(row, index) in rows">
```

And your code just works perfect if remove `photo` component, are you sure that you dont have any errors in console?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
el:'#app',
  data: {
  rows: []
  },
  methods:{
  addRow: function(){
                 this.rows.push({photo: ""});
                }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js">
</script>
<div id=app>
 <div :id="'photo'+index" class="row" v-for="(row,index) in rows">
                        <div class="col-3">
                           {{row.photo+index}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="button btn-primary" 
@click="addRow">Add row</button>
</div>
```